# Get data when login by facebook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have this function to log in by facebook method in firebase with React Native :

```
async handleFacebookButton() {
  const navigation = this.props.navigation;
  const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, {
    permissions: ['public_profile', 'email']
  });
  if (type === 'success') {
    const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
     navigation.navigate("Profile");
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential).catch(error => {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
      alert('please check your email or password');

    });
  }
}
```

And I need to get the user data when login, like username, phone, email. 
how can I get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `.then()` in your `auth.signInWithCredential()`. Then you'd have something like:

```
auth.signInWithCredential().then(user => {
  // user is the signed in user, for which you can get details
})
```